# what inequality if any must hold between sin a and sin b?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\frac{17\pi}2 < a< b <\frac{19\pi}2$

What inequality if any must hold between $\sin a$ and $\sin b$?

I did it this way:

$\frac{17\pi}2=\frac{\pi}2$ and $\frac{19\pi}2=\frac{3\pi}2$ thus the condition is equivalent to saying that

$$\frac{\pi}2 < a < b < \frac{3\pi}2$$

Thus we have $$\sin(\frac{\pi}2)< \sin a < \sin b <\sin (\frac{3\pi}2)$$

-->$$0 < \sin a < \sin b<-1$$

is this right?

Comment: This doesn't ask a clear question. There are infinitely many inequalities that could be made between $\text{sin } a$ and $\text{sin } b$ given these conditions. Off the top of my head, you could make quite a few using Taylor polynomials.

Comment: Please note that $\frac{17\pi}{2} \neq \frac{\pi}{2}$. What you probably meant to say is that $\frac{17\pi}{2} \equiv \frac{\pi}{2} \pmod{2\pi}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, mostly. There are two technical errors here. Most notably is that $\sin(\frac{\pi}2)=1$, whereas you have it as $0$ in your manipulations. Also $\sin$ is *decreasing* on that interval (just look at a graph!) so, the directions of your inequalities are backwards. (You could also note that you just wrote "$0<-1$", which is problematic). So, the proper result would be:
$$1>\sin a > \sin b > -1.$$

Another note is that, even though $\frac{17\pi}2$ and $\frac{\pi}2$ represent the same angle (sometimes said to be "coterminal", meaning they differ by a multiple of $2\pi$), they aren't quite "equal" in the general sense, so it's a bit misleading to say that they are. You could run into trouble if you tried the same exercise but said
$$\frac{17\pi}2<a<b<\frac{23\pi}2$$
which has equivalent conditions when seen as *angles*, but which admits that $\sin b$ could be greater than $\sin a$, since the interval spans more than a complete rotation.